# Return types within a Task running an async anonymous function?

Tags: c#

I have a function that returns a `Task<String>`, to construct this `Task` I have to use an anonymous `async` function because I must `await` multiple calls within the `Task`. I have found that I can return `""` though if I try to return null an error arises (Visual Studio message)

> Anonymous function converted to void returning delegate cannot return a value
>
> Async lambda expression converted to a 'Task' returning delegate cannot return a value. Did you intend to return 'Task'?

A function showing the same issue

```
public virtual Task<String> FooBar()
{
    return Task<String>.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1500);
        return ""; // OK
        //return null; // Error 
    });
}
```

**What is happening here?**

Would it be more appropriate to `return await Task.FromResult<String>(null);` if I would like to return a null value?

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run` in the first place?  You don't have CPU bound work, you have asynchronous work; simply remove that call entirely as it's accomplishing nothing here.

Comment: It's worth noting `Task<String>.Run` is exactly the same as `Task.Run`, as it's a static method on the base class. The compiler still needs to infer the return type from the delegate provided to `Run` (which it can't do with only `null` to go on).

Comment: @CharlesMager that makes sense and clear up another "issue". Visual Studio slightly grays out the `<String>` portion noting that it is not needed. I knew it was inferring the Type somehow but now I see exactly how it does that.

Comment: @Servy the method `FooBar` is meant to create some task to do that could possibly CPU bound. In some cases "real work" is done but in others it is asynchronous. When I wrote the question I had assumed from the error message it had to specifically with using an `async` function, though now I see that is not the case.

Comment: @KDecker If that's the case that that specific CPU bound operation should be wrapped in a call to `Task.Run`, not the whole method, including operations that aren't CPU bound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler does not know that `null` is a string's null and therefor can't automatically choose the correct type `Func<Task<string>>`. Do the following instead to tell the compiler that the null is for a string.

```
return (string)null;
```

---

Also, as brought up in the comments, `Task.Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> function)` is a static method so when you do `Task<String>.Run(...` you are still calling the same static method `Task.Run` with no extra information. What you need to do instead is call it and pass the type in to the `Run` portion forcing the return type to be `string` instead of making the compiler try and figure out what the return type should be.

```
public virtual Task<String> FooBar()
{
    return Task.Run<String>(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1500);
        return null; // Does not error 
    });
}
```

Comment: Just beat me! Alternatively, you can use `Task.Run<String>`.

Comment: FYI, You can use `Task.Run<string>(...)` instead of `Task<string>.Run(...)`

Comment: Or `default(string)`

Comment: Oh interesting I've never seen a "casted null" if that's the proper terminology.

Comment: @StephenCleary I honestly did not think of that option, if you posted an answer I would upvote it.

Comment: @StephenCleary did you mean `string` (lowercase) instead of `String` (as I have in my question)? I forget what is the name for the distinction between these two types? I have been meaning to go through and change all of my uses of the capital letter versions, and also ask a question if its a "problem" to use them.

Comment: @KDecker The more common use of if (at least for me) is when you are trying to pass `null` in to a function that has a `params` value and you are not getting the behavior you want. As for `String` vs `string` there is no difference in this case `string` is a built in alias of `System.String`. My personal coding style, I use `string` when I am referring to the type (like in a cast or a variable declaration) and use `String` when I want to call one of the static methods on the class (Because `string.Join(...)` looks weird to me).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain just out of interest what do you mean by "not getting the behavior you want"? What is the expected and misbehavior you would see in that instance?

Comment: @KDecker I can't remember off the top of my head, but when you are getting a null `Foo[]` being passed in when you really wanted a `Foo[1]` with the first element being `null`, or vica versa. I am not near a compiler so I can't test which one `(Foo)null` or `(Foo[])null` is the fix for that problem.

Comment: @KDecker: No, it has nothing to do with the caps (`String` and `string` are the same type). It's where it goes: it should be a type parameter of the method (`Run`), not a type parameter of the type (`Task`).

Comment: @KDecker I got a chance to test it, if you do `Test(null);` to `void Test(params Foo[] foos)`  the variable passed in will be the equivalent to `foos = null;`. if you do `Test((Foo)null);` the variable passed in will be the equivalent to `foos = new Foo[] { null };`. I also updated my answer with a explanation of what Stephen Cleary was taking about in his comment.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you for looking into that, I see what you mean now. // I guess I am not sure how I never noticed the difference between `Task<T>.Run` and `Task.Run<T>`, after looking out of the few tens of `Task` I create there a handful of spots where I use the later pattern. // Care to mention here or in the answer why the distinction even exists if the type can just be inferred when using `Task<T>`?

Comment: @KDecker It exists because `Task<T>` inherits `Task`, so all static methods on `Task` also show up on `Task<T>`. They could have done in `Task<T>` `new public static Task<T> Run(Func<Task<T>> function)` but if that feature was discussed [it never got enough points to be included](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/).